# "your location could not be determined" google maps for mobile with android 4.2.2

Tags: android

I have a mobile phone SAMSUNG with Android OS 4.2.2 and when I accept to share and display my current location in google maps a message is displayed on my mobile screen "your location could not be determined".. I have done all the updates to my software and of course I have activated all location settings in mobile.

Is this is known issue-bug? How can I resolve this issue?
I noticed that last time I faced the same issue i performed return to factory setting and the issue was resolved.

Comment: https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1250066?hl=en

Comment: Not helpful at all. Steps repeated 3 times. Still not working. Probably this is a bug for android 4.2.2. In android 4.4 and 4.3 no issue with current location. Besides it is not the first time I use Google Maps in my mobile browser. I used it the last 3 months with no problems with displaying current location.

Comment: not bug its tested in my app ........ have u forget someyhing

Comment: it is not the first time I use Google Maps in my mobile browser. I used it the last 3 months with no problems with displaying current location. After updates on my mobile problem appeared.